# Insert commands in a opend command prompt

Tags: php, windows

I'm having a problem with the **hl2.exe** command prompt.

I'm wondering if there is a way to insert commands via php into a open command prompt?

Update:

The command prompt is allready open i need to insert new commands i to the existing and opend prompt.

Comment: Er... Actually what???

Comment: ergh, I hate asking this, but "and you tried what?"

Comment: I didnt tryed anything yet because i have now clue how to do it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using exec in php.

```
exec("hl2.exe <parameter1> <parameter2> <cvar1> <cvar2>");
```

Comment: worth pointing out this VERY dangerous. You MUST ensure any user input is very carefully validated.

Comment: I actually know this. The commad promt is allready open and i want to insert text into the allready opend commandline.